# GDI exception when save image

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my code:

```
protected void Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    img3.Src = img1.Src;

    img3.Width = Int32.Parse(imgWidth.Text);
    img3.Height = Int32.Parse(imgHeight.Text);

    String saveDir = "~/Images/rect/";
    Image rimg = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(img3.Src));
    Rectangle section = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(Int32.Parse(imgw.Value), Int32.Parse(imgh.Value)));
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(rimg, section.Size);
    Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(b);
    b.Save(Server.MapPath(saveDir + "rec" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".jpg"));
}
```

The error is in this line :

`b.Save(Server.MapPath(saveDir + "rec" + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyhhmmss") + ".jpg"));`

The error is :

> `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error
>   occurred in GDI+.

Comment: There are quite a few possible causes for that error, like files being locked, images being in the wrong format and graphics objects not being disposed. What have you tried?

Comment: solved thanks i forgot to make the folder rect in images. but its not what i have expected.. what i want is to save the image as the resized size but has a rectangle as the original image size